# Can't loop through my Array and return a new Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to loop through `var algos` , add it to the end of the URL, then have it return the new array `urllist`. I keep getting an empty an empty array. I don't get any errors thrown so it makes me think its a scope issue.

Here is my code:

```js
var algos =  ["SCRYPT","X11","DAGGERHASIMOTO" ];
let urllist = new Array();
// creates the url list 
function buildlist  () 
{
  
  for (let i=0; i < algos.length; i++){
  let urllink = 'https://api2.nicehash.com/main/api/v2/public/algo/history?algorithm='+algos[i];
  urllist.push(urllink);
};
return urllist 
};

console.log(urllist);
```

In my understanding of Js, `function buildlist` should have access to the global variable `let urllist= new Array();`

It's probably something small I'm overlooking. I've seen other answers on SO and I believe my for loop and function is written properly.

Thanks fellow SO hackers.

Comment: Calling your function would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prefer pure functions for better code quality. The pure function should return something that was calculated by its arguments only. Avoid using global vars when you can avoid these.

```js
function buildlist (incomingArray) 
{       
  let urllist = new Array();
  for (let i=0; i < incomingArray.length; i++) {
     urllist.push('https://api2.nicehash.com/main/api/v2/public/algo/history?algorithm='+incomingArray[i]);
  };
  return urllist;
};

console.log( buildlist(["SCRYPT","X11","DAGGERHASIMOTO"]) );
```

Comment: This does look cleaner and idiomatic . Thank you @JohnPan

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring the function but you didn't invoke it;
try adding `buildlist()` just before the console.log

Answer (score 0):

So this is how the solution should look:

```
var algos =  ["SCRYPT","X11","DAGGERHASIMOTO" ];

function buildlist (incomingArray) 
{       
  let urllist = new Array();
  for (let i=0; i < incomingArray.length; i++) {
     urllist.push('https://api2.nicehash.com/main/api/v2/public/algo/history?algorithm='+incomingArray[i]);
  };
  return urllist;
};

// prints the list to the console
console.log( buildlist(algos) );
```